# What Big-O equation describes my search?

Tags: big-o, binary-search

I have a sorted array of doubles (latitudes actually) that relatively uniformally spread out over a range of -10 to -43. Now, if I did a binary search over that list I get O(log N).

But, I can further optimise by search by having a lookup table where I have 34 keys (-10 to -43) that can then jump straight to the starting point of that number.

Eg: -23.123424 first look up key 23 and know the start-end range of all -23 values. I can then binary search from the middle of that.

What would my Big-O look like?

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to achieve something very much like a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)

Comment: @BrianRoach Although, even a skip list has O(log n) lookup complexity. Their only advantage vs a vanilla binary tree is their auto-balancing properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's still O(log n). Consider: it takes constant time to look up the starting indices in your integer lookup table, so that part doesn't add anything. Then it's O(log n) to do the binary search. Actually it will take roughly log n/34 because you expect to search through an array 34 times smaller on average (the values are distributed in 34 different intervals with boundaries from -43 to -10), but constant multipliers aren't considered in big-O notation.

Comment: And log(n / 34) = log(n) - log(34).  So there isn't even a constant multiplier here.

Answer (score 1):

It would still be `O(log N)`, but for a reduced dataset (think smaller value for N).

Since the lookup table provides ca. 1/34, which is close to 1/32 or 5 steps in the binary search, you might want to benchmark, if this really helps things: The additional code paths with lots of cache misses and one or the other wrong branch prediction/pipeline clearing might make this slower than the direct binary search.

Additionally, if lookup time for an in-memory table is the bottleneck, you might want to consider representing your lats as `Int32` values - definitly precise enough, but much faster to search through.

Comment: There is another reason besides speed to use 32-bit integers instead of floating point for anything that's an angle (including latitudes and longitude): with floating point, values closer to zero have more precision available (more decimal places stores losslessly) and values far away from zero have less. Yet there is no good reason why points closer to the equator should be stored more precisely than other points. Integers scaled so that 0 means 0 and 2147483648 means π radians are equivalent to fixed-point fractional numbers and are good for this application.

Comment: I will do that for sure! A big payoff and since I already am generating the data in to a file I will just pre-convert to 32 bit. Very nice.

Comment: @Celada Ofcourse you are right, but I suspect this to have little real-world consequences: I suspect values between -10 and -43 as in the OQ to have a float precision, that is much better than the data (GPS?) quality. Also the data origin is `float`, so rescaling will not introduce a new precision, that was not there in the original data. Nevertheless we agree on `int` being the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your optimization would help, but I'm thinking it's still considered O(log N) because you still have to search the exact value.  If it took you directly to the value it would be O(1)

This is a limitation of the Big-Oh analysis.  It doesn't take in account that you reduced the amount of values you have to search.

Comment: Sure it does, but it only makes a difference if the optimization causes a reduction in the asymptotic complexity of the number of elements to search. Big-Oh is really nothing more than asymptotic number of operations needed for the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept is close to that of [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search), except instead of only "interpolating" once on the integral part of the key, it recursively uses interpolation to intelligently drive a binary search. Since your domain is relatively uniform, the expected runtime is `O(log log n)`.

Comment: In code would that be like: I have -23.1234 so i jump to "roughly" the percentage of -23 is in -10 to -43. THen I look at the value, say it's -33. So then I now jump a certain percentage between -10 to -33, and so on?

Comment: @peterept Correct. The more uniform the input, the more liekly you will jump to the correct entry.